# Check if fields exist in other table

Tags: sql

I have two queries, one is to check the no. of times the `STUDENTNO` exists in the table `Subjects`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM Subjects R  
INNER JOIN students w W ON R.studentno = W.studentno 
WHERE R.studentno = '89514'
```

Next is to get the valid `students` (whose name and student no doesn't exist in the table `SUBJECT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT W. * 
FROM STUDENTS W 
LEFT JOIN SUBJECTS R ON W.STUDENTNO + w.NAME = R.STUDENTNO + r.NAME   
WHERE R.STUDENTNO + r.NAME IS NULL
```

I didn't get any output here. I still need to get those whose `STUDENTNO` exist in the `SUBJECT` table, but I guess this doesn't retrun it. Help. Please. Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the `+` signs to do?

Comment: to combine the two fields (serves as primary key)

Comment: That's not a good way to do it.  You should write ON W.StudentNo = R.StudentNo AND W.Name = R.Name.  There are numerous reasons for that.

Answer (score 1):

Couple suggestions for your second query:

- use **meaningful** table aliases! Why is `Students` aliased to be `W` ??
- if you want to join on multiple columns - do so separate, not by concatenating together two columns... also: is `StudentNo` a primary key?? If so: checking for the primary key to match would be sufficient - no need to add an extra condition that doesn't add any value to the JOIN.....

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stu.* 
FROM Students stu
LEFT JOIN Subjects sub ON stu.StudentNo = sub.StudentNo AND stu.Name = sub.Name  
WHERE sub.StudentNo IS NULL
```

or if `StudentNo` is the primary key, then maybe this will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stu.* 
FROM Students stu
LEFT JOIN Subjects sub ON stu.StudentNo = sub.StudentNo 
WHERE sub.StudentNo IS NULL
```

Does that return anything??

Comment: ahh. i just forgot to edit it with my original query, tables and columns . never tought it would be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The first query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Subjects
 WHERE StudentNo = '89514';
```

The second can probably be simplified to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Students
 WHERE StudentNo NOT IN (SELECT StudentNo FROM Subjects);
```

This formulation does assume that the names in the Subjects table match the names in the Students table.  The design of the database is (seriously) flawed if the student name is recorded in the Subjects table too.  For instance, you can't update the name in the Students table without also updating the matching rows in the Subjects table - which is bad.